# Merging two strings of numbers

Tags: php

I have two strings, both consist of numbers.

```
$str1 = '2,3,6,8,99';
$str2 = '44,22,4,3,6';
```

I would like to merge them in a way that will sort them from smallest to largest and will not have duplicate values. So I thought the best way is to use array functions;

```
$str1 = explode(', ', $str1 );
$str2 = explode(', ', $str2 );
$merged= array_merge($str1, $str2);
sort($merged); // sort low to high
$str3 = array_unique($merged); // remove duplicates
$str3 = implode(', ', $str3 );
```

Looks about right, but I still get duplicates and the list is not ordered... What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure this should work, I will try it in a few minutes.

```
$tempStr1 = explode(',',$str1);
$tempStr2 = explode(',',$str2);

$tempArr = array_merge($tempStr1, $tempStr2);
$tempArr = array_unique($tempArr);
echo implode(',', $tempArr);
```

[edit]
It looks like you solved it..

Answer (score 5):

You are exploding on the wrong delimiter. Note the extra space `,`.

Comment: Coffee, I need more coffee... Thanks.